# How do you call the main method of a java class from jruby?

Tags: java, jruby

Hi I am using JRuby to interact with a Java class. I have successfully imported the java class into my jruby program and created a new instance. However when I create the instance, I cannot call the main method. I can call every other method like object.method but I can't do object.main. How do I access the main method of a java class through jruby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main is usually static - don't you want ClassName.main?